# tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: tensorflow

I built TensorFlow from source on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I got the following error:

tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

```
$ bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package 

...

cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package
INFO: Elapsed time: 3222.284s, Critical Path: 2243.74s
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-32:~/tensorflow$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
Tue Mar 21 22:17:06 UTC 2017 : === Using tmpdir: /tmp/tmp.JVDbpc8IYs
~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles ~/tensorflow
~/tensorflow
/tmp/tmp.JVDbpc8IYs ~/tensorflow
Tue Mar 21 22:17:07 UTC 2017 : === Building wheel
warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.lib' under directory '*'
~/tensorflow
Tue Mar 21 22:17:29 UTC 2017 : === Output wheel file is in: /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl 
tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log

ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-202:~$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-202:~$ man pip
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-202:~$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

vi /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log:

tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 168, in from_line
    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)
UnsupportedWheel: tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I'm getting the same error with a protobuf wheel:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl 
protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be your pip is outdated? Try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

It might also help to inspect the logs in `/home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: Could this be a 32-bit system, and you're installing a 64-bit wheel?

Comment: ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-213:/usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-1-213 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

`cp27` in `tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl` means it is for python-2.7.

Answer (score 0):

sudo retrieved the 3.4 version of 'pip' (instead of the 2.7 version):

ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-152:~/tensorflow$ sudo pip --version 
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.4.egg (python 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\Scripts>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages (20.0.2)

(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\Scripts>pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-py2-none-any.whl
tensorflow-1.0.1-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6xom.png)